# Curl : get instagram account followers count

Tags: php, curl, instagram

I'm trying to display the number of Instagram followers of my users. They log in on my wordpress website with Instagram, I'm using the pluggin Social Login.

Apparently it is not possible anymore to do it with the Instagram API since they've closed the endpoint, hence I'm trying to achieve it with Curl by editing my functions.php file in my Child Theme folder.

```
<?php
// Variable to get the user's instagram nickname
$user_id = get_current_user_id(); 
  $key = 'nickname'; 
  $single = true; 
  $user_nickname = get_user_meta( $user_id, $key, $single );
//create cURL connection
$curl_connection = 
curl_init("https://www.instagram.com/$user_nickname/?__a=1");

//set options 

curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 
  "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);


//perform our request
$result = curl_exec($curl_connection);



//close the connection
curl_close($curl_connection);


$start = strpos($result, '"edge_followed_by":{"count":');

$end = strpos($result, '}', $start);

$length = $end-$start;

$result = substr($result, 28, -1);

echo $result;
?>
```

I expect to display the user's Instagram followers count, but echo returns nothing.

Comment: Do not switch VERIFY_PEER off!

Answer (score 0):

I think changing this line:

```
$curl_connection = 
curl_init("https://www.instagram.com/$user_nickname/?__a=1");
```

to the following:

```
$curl_connection=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_connection,CURLOPT_URL,'https://www.instagram.com/$user_nickname/?__a=1');
```

should do the trick.

Please let me know.

Comment: With this correction, data is indeed echoed on the website, however it does not load a valid instagram page. It might be a problem with the $user_nickname. However, when i replace the URL by a static URL, ie. replacing $user_nickname with a name, the website becomes blank.

Comment: I think it is not working because Instagram blocks the request. Thanks for your help.